# Worksheet Tab name change based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the worksheet tab names based on the cell value its changing only in sheet 1 other sheets not changing

nothing

```
Public Sub ChangeSheetNames()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'For i = 2 To lastRow
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    'ws.Tab = ws.Cells(i, 2)

       If ws.Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
          ws.Name = ws.Range("A2").Value
       End If

    Next ws
End Sub
```

changing only for sheet 1 I need to change min 50 sheets

Comment: Note that because of `On Error Resume Next` you don't see the errors (it hides all the messages) but the errors still occur! Remove that line and fix your errors. • For your issue see also https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2790229/step-by-step-rename-excel-sheet-with-cell-contents-by-using-macro

Comment: Your code is working just fine. I do not get any problem with your code.

Comment: If it is not renaming the other sheets then it means that there is no value in cell A2 of those sheets. Physically check by clicking on that cell and checking if there is any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this macro:

```
Public Sub ChangeSheetNames()
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    With Worksheets(1)
        lLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then Worksheets(i).Name = .Cells(i, 1).Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You should `Dim i As Long` and `Rows.Count` must start with a dot `.Rows.Count`.

Comment: I need one more help for this 1st 3sheets dont change the name from 4th sheet only change the tab names how can i set

Comment: Have in mind that if you try to change sheet name with a name that already exist you will receive an error.